# Splitting text and wrapping each of the words in elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

PS: Updated Fiddle

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUUbW/) that wraps text in elements

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUUbW/70/) trying to split text using commas as delimiters and wrap each of the words in `<span class="new"/>`. Would anyone please tell me why it gives me `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the foreach loop?

I want the output to be

```
 <td>
     <span class='new'>Text</span>
     <span class='new'>that</span>
     <span class='new'>needs</span>
     <span class='new'>to</span>
     <span class='new'>be</span>
     <span class='new'>wrapped.</span>
     <span class="count">not this</span>
     <button>Wrap</button>
 </td>
```

Code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var wrap_it = $(this).closest('td').contents().eq(0).text();
    wrap_it = wrap_it.split(',');
    console.log(wrap_it);

    $.each(wrap_it,function(i,k){
      k.wrap('<span class="new"/>');
    })

});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
       <td>Text,that, needs, to, be, wrapped.<span class="count">not this</span><button>Wrap</button>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Text, that, needs, to, be, wrapped.<span class="count">not this</span><button>Wrap</button></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a try:

```
$('button').click(function(){    
    var text = $(this).closest('td').contents().eq(0).text().split(",");
    var keep = $(this).closest('td').find(".count");
    var button = $(this).closest('td').find('button');
       for( var i = 0, len = text.length; i < len; i++ ) {
           text[i] = '<span class="new">' + text[i] + '</span>';
       }   
    $(this).closest('td').html(text.join(' ')).append(keep).append(button);  
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qUUbW/126/)

Tell me please if it suits you.

Comment: I don't understand why this was the accepted answer, as it doesn't comply with the OP's expected output. `<span class="count">not this</span> <button>Wrap</button>` has been removed in the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @matthias_h. Wasn't sure if he needs to keep  button and text inside `.count` class. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Also made a try

```
$('button').click(function () {

  var text = $(this).closest('td').contents().eq(0).text().split(','),
      len = text.length,
      result = []; 

for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    result[i] = '<span class="new">' + text[i] + '</span>';
}
var keep = $(this).closest('td').find(".count"),
    button = $(this).closest('td').find('button');
$(this).closest('td').html(result.join(' ')).append(keep).append(button);   
});
```

With Fiddle: 
[Wrap splitted text](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/qUUbW/116/)