# JQuery Looping a slice(), split(), and wrapped array...for each element of class

Tags: jquery, split, each, slice

I'm pretty sure I'm close to this one but i just can't seem to get it right. Im getting the following strings dynamically for each event listed, always in the same format. basically need to split() off the Date for each of these entries and return only the times, which are split() at the ',' and rendered in spans
This is what I've got:

```
<div class="date">Di 22.10.2014 um 14:00, 18:00</div>
<div class="date">Di 22.10.2014 um 14:00, 18:00, 20:00 </div>
```

and

```
var data =$('.date').html().slice(17);
var arr = data.split(',');
$(".date").empty();
$.each(arr, function(i, v) { 
$('.date').append($("<span>").html(v));
});
```

.... so far so good... this http://jsfiddle.net/MealaBmay/K3D6d/1088/ is working, BUT
I've realised each '.date' was ending up with the same content. I can't seem to get this script converted to do this for each  ...
I looked at [Splitting text and wrapping each of the words in elements in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473509/splitting-text-and-wrapping-each-of-the-words-in-elements-in-jquery)
and tried to use the same method....but *sigh* keep drawing a blank...any helpers out there? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setter version of [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) which takes a callback function

```js
$('.date').each(function(i, text) {
  var $this = $(this),
    data = $this.text().slice(17);
  var arr = data.split(',');
  $this.empty();
  $.each(arr, function(i, v) {
    $this.append($("<span>").html(v));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">Di 22.10.2014 um 14:00, 18:00</div>
<div class="date">Di 22.10.2014 um 14:00, 18:00, 20:00</div>
```

---

Probably another way to do the same

```js
$('.date').html(function(i, html) {
  return $.map(html.trim().substring(17).split(','), function(item) {
    return '<span>' + item + '</span>'
  }).join('')
})
```

```css
.date span {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">Di 22.10.2014 um 14:00, 18:00</div>
<div class="date">Di 22.10.2014 um 14:00, 18:00, 20:00</div>
```

Comment: Okay... this is nice as an alternate way to do the trim, but after return i can't re-split and wrap the times...something i had actually already managed to do...

Comment: yes... but the wrapping of each after the split .... sorry but im stuck and everything i try (.each, for , and the method i used before) gets me an error 'unreachable after return'

Comment: jquery version used? where is the error from? is it from a compilation tool?

Comment: just plain fiddle set to JQ 1.9.1, the platform i use in the end doest give me a lot of options for debugging